# Godaddy php session not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, session-variables

I am having an issue where PHP sessions are returning the wrong values when uploaded to a godaddy (linux) hosting environment. This works locally on my wampserver (windows 10) absolutely fine. I am simply trying to use Abrahams twitter library, and as mentioned works locally.

The code is quite simple:
2 Files, 
index.html:

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL ); 
session_save_path('/home/aureagle/public_html/sgorilla.com/sessions');
session_start();

echo "<br>" . session_save_path() . "<br>";

require "twitteroauth/autoload.php";

use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'xxx');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET',     'yyy');
define('OAUTH_CALLBACK', 'http://www.sgorilla.com/report.php');

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

$request_token = $connection->oauth('oauth/request_token',     array('oauth_callback' => OAUTH_CALLBACK));

$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

$url = $connection->url('oauth/authorize', array('oauth_token' => $request_token['oauth_token']));  
?>
```

...

And a url to click:

Then after the user is returned from twitter, report.html is called:

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL ); 
session_save_path('/home/aureagle/public_html/sgorilla.com/sessions');
session_start();

var_dump($_SESSION);
echo "<br>";

echo "<br>" . session_save_path() . "<br>";

require "twitteroauth/autoload.php";

use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'xxxx');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'yyyy');

$request_token = [];
$request_token['oauth_token'] = $_SESSION['oauth_token'];
$request_token['oauth_token_secret'] = $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'];

if (isset($_REQUEST['oauth_token']) && $request_token['oauth_token'] !==    $_REQUEST['oauth_token']) {
// Abort! Something is wrong.
echo "<br>abort!";
}
```

The _SESSION is completely different to before, wrong auth values completely. I've spent hours checking paths, changing paths, clearing sessions, deleting sessions - all sorts but for some reason the session is different.

Godaddy support can't help (just got off the phone) and i've spent a whole day with this already.

Can anyone please give me some suggestions? It's very annoying something quite simple isn't working.

The session save path was /tmp, changing it to the path specified doesn't change anything (I do see sessions appear, but weirdly after a short delay which is suspect).

As you can see from the script Abort is output everytime as the values don;t match up.

Any ideas on what to try next? I've tried deleting the session files also but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

TIA!

Comment: To add some more info, I checked the session file, .First deleted them all, refreshed index.html, checked the sessions directory. a session had appeared, but it's contents were wrong. Right vars (I added one as a test which was correct) but the auth values are different. confused.

Comment: also confirmed the session id is correct between pages, but on the first page the contents of the session file are incorrect. Does anyone know why this might happen?

Comment: im making progress but need to hand to cross the finish line! I noticed that when using session_regenerate_id I got 4 (FOUR!) sessions created. It then occured to me that maybe htaccess was being silly, lo and behold there was a htaccess (shared hosting remember and we have other sites running) setup for wordpress. I created a new .htaccess file with simply RewriteBase / in it, now I get one valid session but a further empty one (0 bytes). Does anyone know what should be in the htaccess file?

Comment: ok so I resorted to turning off the pretty links feature on wordpress for the main website (not an addon domain).